# Magento 2.3: Orders Status not updating.All new orders stuck at "Processing" status

Tags: magento2.3, admin-panel, order-status

In SALES > ORDERS Status should be "Complete". But Status still shows as "Processing".
i have run :

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
> php bin/magento cache:clean

Still show Processing state.How can i Resolve this.
Temporary solution available :

> UPDATE sales_order_grid as t1 LEFT JOIN sales_order as t2 ON
>   t1.entity_id = t2.entity_id SET t1.status = t2.status WHERE t1.status
>   != t2.status"

But i want permanent solution for this issue.

Comment: Is Invoice and shipment done for all items?

Comment: are you using observer?

Comment: @ChandreshP. yes, order in complete state,, but show in pending state

Comment: @AsadUllah not use any observer.

Comment: <event name="sales_order_invoice_pay">
        <observer name="observer_controller_status_update"
                  instance="Progos\Assignment\Observer\OrderStatusUpdate"/>
    </event>

try using this observer hope it helps

Comment: using this observer run this query ?